# odeint running problems: nan and exceeding integration limits

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

In the following code, I am trying to solve an ODE using SciPy's odeint. `sigma_sq` is a monotonically decreasing function, and in the function `Ptot` I take a fractional power of `sigma_sq(m) - sigma_sq(m0)`, where `m` should always be smaller than `m0`. But, when running `odeint`, python returns an error `negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power`. This happens when `P1(m)` is called in `rhs`, and when I print the values `m,m0` I see that `m` exceeds `m0`, even though in `mlist` the maximal value is `m0`.

Another problem I have is that the function returns `nan` for later iterations.

```
x1 = 0.44
sigma8 = 0.82
spectral_index = 0.971
m0 = 1e13
dw = 1e-6

def sigma_sq(m):
    return sigma8**2 * m**((-2*(spectral_index+3.))/3.)
def dsdm(m):
    return (-2.*(spectral_index+3.)/3.) * m**((-2*(spectral_index+3.))/3. - 1)
def heavi(m):
    if type(m) == numpy.float64:
        return (1 if m > 0 else 0)
    else:
        return np.array([(1 if mv>0 else 0) for mv in m])
def Ptot(m):
    print sigma_sq(m) - sigma_sq(m0),m,m0
    return (1./np.sqrt(2.*np.pi)) * (m0/m) * (dw / (sigma_sq(m) - sigma_sq(m0))**(3./2.)) * np.abs(dsdm(m))
def P1(m):
    return Ptot(m)*np.heaviside(m-x1*m0,1./2.)
def P2(m):
    return Ptot(m) - P1(m)

def rhs(f,m):
    return -P1(m)/P2(f)

mlist2 = np.linspace(x1*m0,m0,10000)
y0 = x1*m0
f2 = odeint(rhs,y0,mlist2)
```

Comment: In general, the `odeint` solver will make internal steps beyond the last value given in the `t` argument, in order to accurately compute the value of the solution at the last `t` value.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser This is the reason that if I put a maximal value of `0.99*m0` it does not return error?

Comment: Probably.  But using `0.99*m0` doesn't guarantee it won't go past `m0` if you run it again with different parameters.  If your function is very smooth, the adaptive solver can take very big steps, and it might still go past `m0` when it gets near `0.99*m0`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser is there a way to prevent odeint from exceeding beyond the last value?

Comment: @Joshhh you could modify your function to perform range checks and return a sensible value other than NaN if the input exceeds its maximum value.